# Как с помощью gulp упорядочить сборку?

Tags: gulp, postcss

Решил перейти на `Gulp` и `PostCSS`, как в данном сборщике определить порядок сборки CSS? При этом на выходе должно быть 2 файла, один минифицированный, другой нет. Код из `gulpfile.js`

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var cssnano = require('cssnano');
var nested = require('postcss-nested');
var short = require('postcss-short');
var assets = require('postcss-assets');
var cssnext = require('postcss-cssnext');

gulp.task('css', function () {
    var processors = [
        //autoprefixer({browsers: ['last 12 version']}),
        //nested,
        //cssnano(),
        short,
        assets({
            loadPaths: ['app/src/assets/'],
            relativeTo: 'app/common.css'
        }),
        cssnext,
    ];
    return gulp.src('css/*/*.css')
        .pipe(postcss(processors))
        .pipe(rename('common.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'));
});

gulp.task('default', function(){
    gulp.watch('css/*/*.css', function(){
        gulp.run('css');
    })
});
```

Comment: Вместо `css/*/*.css` перечисляйте ваши css в нужном порядке, если вы это имеете в виду.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian я пробовал делать сборку вида `gulp.src(['css/reset.css,css/blablabla.css,etc.’])`, не вышло почему-то. А как быть с минифицированием и двумя разными файлами?

Comment: Правильно перечислять так `['css/reset.css', 'css/blablabla.css']`. Для минифицированого варианта сделайте второй таск.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian все прелестно, кроме переменных, что в другом файле, из-за этого не собирает. Возможно при `PostCSS` тоже есть какой фал регулирующий данную сборку, например как это делается при `LESS` и `SASS`